# Excel VBA: How to use changing cell values in For Each statement?

Tags: vba, excel

So I've build the following Macro that almost captures whats it needs to do. It copies data form one sheet3, pastes the data in sheet1. After which it replaces variables1-7 with values that are to be found in sheet2.

The Macro works just fine when it is Executed for one row. However I would like it to loop through all the filled in rows in Sheet2 and replace the variables with the corresponding row values in Sheet2.

Hoping to find the answer here, since I'm quite new to VBA and haven't been able to find the answer yet.

```
Sub Macro1()

For Each c In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:G13").Rows

Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
Range("A1:AH125").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Selection.Replace What:="Variable1", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="Variable2", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="Variable3", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="Variable4", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="Variable5", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E").Value, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="Variable6", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="Variable7", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to loop through all sheet2 values and replace with values from sheet2?  Do you mean sheet3?

Comment: Yes, the replacement values are to be found in sheet2. Sheet3 contains the info that is pasted in Sheet1 by the first part of the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have obviously created this macro with the Macro recorder.  That is a good place to start when trying to understand the syntax of a new statement.  However, the Macro recorder does not know your objective and records each little step as a single statement.  It is necessary to tidy up and combine these statements before trying to put a loop round them.

Consider:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
Range("A1:AH125").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I can replace that with:

```
  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:AH125").Copy _
                   Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1)
```

I have retained your statement to calculate `lMaxRows` but have replaced all the other statements with a single `Copy` statement.  The syntax of this statement is:

```
SourceRange.Copy Destination:=TopLeftCellOfDestination
```

The `Destination:=` is optional but it helps make the syntax clearer.

I have not switched worksheets or selected anything.  This VBA is much faster and, once you have mastered the syntax, it is easier to understand what the VBA is doing.

Now consider:

```
Selection.Replace What:="Variable1", Replacement:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

The `Selection` will have to go because I have not selected anything.  But the real problem is:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A").Value
```

which is invalid VBA and does include the For variable `c`.

The correct object is:

```
c.Columns("A").Value
```

`c` is a range for example `A2:G2` or `A13:G13`.  I have taken column A of the range to give me `A2` or `A13`.  I have then taken the value of that cell.

To replace the `Selection` I have placed `With` statement around the outside of this `Replace` block to give the code below which I believe does what you want:

```
Sub Macro1()

For Each c In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:G13").Rows

  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:AH125").Copy _
                   Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1)

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range(.Cells(lMaxRows + 1, "A"), .Cells(lMaxRows + 126, "AH"))

     .Replace What:="Variable1", Replacement:=c.Columns("A").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
         ReplaceFormat:=False
     .Replace What:="Variable2", Replacement:=c.Columns("B").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
     .Replace What:="Variable3", Replacement:=c.Columns("C").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
     .Replace What:="Variable4", Replacement:=c.Columns("D").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
     .Replace What:="Variable5", Replacement:=c.Columns("E").Value, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
     .Replace What:="Variable6", Replacement:=c.Columns("F").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
     .Replace What:="Variable7", Replacement:=c.Columns("G").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    End With
  End With

Next

End Sub
```